# How to fix this BATCH file so that when it is execute and find all the path correctly?

Tags: windows, windows-7, batch-file, windows-installer

I wrote this script to first install the msi and then copy my application to a temporary directory. But none is working. When the `windows.bat` file is executed it failed to find `package\` and also `dist` directory

1) User downloaded and execute the windows.bat file which has following tree:

```
C:\Users\Username\Downloads\windows.bat
C:\Users\Username\Downloads\package\<.msi files>
C:\Users\Username\Downloads\dist\<application files>
```

2) windows.bat contain below:

```
msiexec /I "package\files.msi" /qb
set temp=%TEMP%
echo %temp%
xcopy dist %temp% /e /h /R
```

All fails, to run with windows.bat file. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are you executing the batch file from the C:\Users\Username\Downloads\ directory on a command line, or just from, say, the Run prompt?  It sounds like its working folder is not correct.

Comment: @NickShaw: That directory yes. Both command line and double click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following line to the beginning of your batch file:

```
cd c:\users\username\downloads
```

alternatively, you can do this:

```
cd /d %~p0
```

%~p0 will take argument #0 (the full path to the batch file) and extract the path from it. The /d option will make sure to also change the current drive if the given path contains a drive specification.

Comment: How would i know what is XYZ default Downloads directory path? Or where did the user downloaded (its not me, i am making it for end user, for my case i manually downloaded in that path).

Comment: That's why I extended my answer. %~p0 is the solution to your problem.

Comment: You are right. Forgot about this. I will update the answer for anyone that may stumble upon it in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, think I know what's wrong.  `msiexec.exe` runs from the Windows System folder (e.g. C:\Windows\Systeme32) so when you pass it the name of the msi file to install, you need to include the full path to it.

So, using @MikeNakis' info about getting the current path within the batch file, try this (slight tweak to use %~dp0 for just the directory, so not including the batch file name too):

```
msiexec /I "%~dp0\package\files.msi" /qb
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are in the correct directory to start off with

```
CD /d c:\users\%USERNAME%\downloads
```

As the first line in your batch file